# Split a string with a specific condition

Tags: string, split, freemarker

I have a variable **X** = "NEFT INDBN12025089250 WHISTLE SOLUTIONS LLP INDB0" which contains a string that I want to display in the output as

**Output** - NEFT INDBN12025089250 WHISTLE SOLUTIONS LLP INDB0 INDBN12025089250

Also, I want this to happen only when the string is having NEFT in the beginning and I don't want to use a substring as I am not sure what is the length of **INDBN12025089250** as it is not constant(i.e Assuming it will change every time.)

eg That i have tried
eg.1
`<#assign TXN_DESC_1="NEFT INDBN12025089250 WHISTLE SOLUTIONS LLP INDB0"?split(" ")> ${TXN_DESC_1[0]} ${TXN_DESC_1[1]} ${TXN_DESC_1[2]} ${TXN_DESC_1[3]} ${TXN_DESC_1[4]} ${TXN_DESC_1[5]} ${TXN_DESC_1[1]}`

eg.2
`x = "NEFT INDBN12025089250 WHISTLE SOLUTIONS LLP INDB0" <#list x?split(r'\s*,\s*''r') as x> ${x} </#list>`

Comment: For the "specific condition" part you can use `#if` or `?then`. Otherwise I'm not sure what exactly the question is, like where do you stuck with solving this.

Comment: x = "NEFT INDBN12025089250 WHISTLE SOLUTIONS LLP INDB0"
<#list x?split(r'\s*,\s*' 'r') as x>
  ${x} 
</#list>
Now iam using this one still not getting the output.
Is there any other way i can get the required output.
How can i get this output,
output - NEFT INDBN12025089250 WHISTLE SOLUTIONS LLP INDB0 INDBN12025089250
from this  X = "NEFT INDBN12025089250 WHISTLE SOLUTIONS LLP INDB0".

Comment: `x?split(r'\s*,\s*' 'r')` splits at comma, but the sample string doesn't use comma at all. Plus this one doesn't attempt to implement the condition, or to repeat the 2nd item at all.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using regular expression replace:

```
${x?replace('^([^ ]+)( INDBN12025089250)(.+)', '$1$2$3$2', 'r')}
```

The tricky thing to realize here is that just like with plain search-and-replace, if the regular expression has no matches, then there's nothing to replace, and therefore `?replace` returns the input string as is. Here, a match will replace the whole string.

Of course in place of `INDBN12025089250` above you can put `${someDynamicValue}` as well, as far as `someDynamicValue` won't contain characters that are reserved in regular expressions.